# Replace some lines in fasta file with appended text using while loop and if/else statement

Tags: bash, unix

I am working with a fasta file and need to add line-specific text to each of the headers. So for example if my file is:

```
>TER1
AGCATGCTAGCTAGTCGACTCGATCGCATGCTC
>TER2
AGCATGCTAGCTAGACGACTCGATCGCATGCTC
>URC1
AGCATGCTAGCTAGTCGACTCGATCGCATGCTC
>URC2
AGCATGCTACCTAGTCGACTCGATCGCATGCTC
>UCR3
AGCATGCTAGCTAGTCGACTCGATGGCATGCTC
```

I want a while loop that will read through each line; for those with a `>` at the start, I want to append `|population:` plus the first three characters after the `>`. So line one would be:

```
>TER1|population:TER
```

etc.

I can't figure out how to make this work. Here my best attempt so far.

```
filename="testfasta.fa"
while read -r line 
do 
    if [[ "$line" == ">"* ]]; then
        id=$(cut -c2-4<<<"$line")
        printf $line"|population:"$id"\n" >>outfile
    else
        printf $line"\n">>outfile
    fi
done <"$filename"
```

This produces a file with the original headers and following line each on a single line.
Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? My if and else loop aren't working at all!
Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your code blocks and removed the empty lines, as I think you only put them there to get linebreaks, right? Also, your loop works for me as is.

Comment: Yes Benjamin W. Thank you! How do I remove the empty lines?

Comment: For proper code blocks, you have to indent by four spaces. Select the code-to-be and use the {} button or press Ctrl-K. In the code block, line breaks are respected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use a `while` loop if you really want,
but `sed` would be simpler:

```
sed -e 's/^>\(...\).*/&|population:\1/' "$filename"
```

That is, for lines starting with `>` (pattern: `^>`),
capture the next 3 characters (with `\(...\)`),
and match the rest of the line (`.*`),
replace with the line as it was (`&`),
and the fixed string `|population:`,
and finally the captured 3 characters (`\1`).

This will produce for your input:

> ```
> >TER1|population:TER
>
> AGCATGCTAGCTAGTCGACTCGATCGCATGCTC
>
> >TER2|population:TER
>
> AGCATGCTAGCTAGACGACTCGATCGCATGCTC
>
> >URC1|population:URC
>
> AGCATGCTAGCTAGTCGACTCGATCGCATGCTC
>
> >URC2|population:URC
>
> AGCATGCTACCTAGTCGACTCGATCGCATGCTC
>
> >UCR3|population:UCR
>
> AGCATGCTAGCTAGTCGACTCGATGGCATGCTC
> ```

Or you can use this `awk`, also producing the same output:

```
awk '{sub(/^>.*/, $0 "|population:" substr($0, 2, 3))}1' "$filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quickly in `awk`:

```
awk '$1~/^>/{$1=$1"|population:"substr($1,2,3)}{}1' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

---

```
$ awk '$1~/^>/{$1=$1"|population:"substr($1,2,3)}{}1' testfile
>TER1|population:TER

AGCATGCTAGCTAGTCGACTCGATCGCATGCTC

>TER2|population:TER

AGCATGCTAGCTAGACGACTCGATCGCATGCTC

>URC1|population:URC

AGCATGCTAGCTAGTCGACTCGATCGCATGCTC

>URC2|population:URC

AGCATGCTACCTAGTCGACTCGATCGCATGCTC

>UCR3|population:UCR

AGCATGCTAGCTAGTCGACTCGATGGCATGCTC
```

Here awk will:

1. Test if the record starts with a `>` The `$1` looks at the first field, but `$0` for the entire record would work just as well in this case. The `~` will perform a regex test, and `^>` means "Starts with `>`". Making the test: (`$1~/^>/`)
2. If so it will set the first field to the output you are looking for (using substr() to get the bits of the string you want. `{$1=$1"|population:"substr($1,2,3)}`
3. Finally it will print out the entire record (with the changes if applicable): `{}1` which is shorthand for `{print $0}` or.. print the entire record.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick suggestions. I went with the sed option. As I'm still learning unix, I would be interested in knowing while my tedious while loop didn't work...

Comment: I'd offer some suggestions but I find the different methods of doing conditions in bash to be completely befuddling. I write them all the time and they never work on my first attempt. Some day I'll figure it out. When dealing with a file though, think sed and awk first. Sed for dealing with the file as a stream that you change as it streams past. Awk for dealing with records and fields (CSVs, logfiles, and whatnot).